# How to flash HP's extracted BIOS file (AmiBIOS-MTTool)

Tags: bios

I updated microcodes in .rom file from extracted BIOS.EXE files
Normally you must install this BIOS update by BIOS.exe file from windows [HP]
but I extracted it and now i have these files[image: extracted bios files] 
is it possible to flash BIOS from these files? from cmd?
I updated bios file so now i can't repack it to .exe file to flash, i need another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done by just opening/running AFUWIN.EXE and then running .bat file.
BIOS will be updated then... That's it... And updated microcodes are in BEN5.37 (ROM) file...